# How to add Enum Properties in ASP.NET Core 6 Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, dropdown, identity

I want to create a dropdown to insert the gender, from Enum .

```
<label asp-for="Gender"></label>
    <select asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" asp-items="@new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(GenderType)))">
        <option selected disabled value="Select">Select GenderType</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core has built-in Html.GetEnumSelectList() method we can use to turn enum members to select list items.

```
            <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Type" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<EnumName>()">
                <option>Select Gender</option>
            </select>
```

[Using Enum in .NET Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-enum-to-select-list/)